# Programmatically exclude/include sites from Google Custom Search JSON API

Tags: python, google-custom-search

I am using the Google Custom Search JSON API to retrieve search results in a json format.

The issue is that the requests only allows for 10 results per time. We need to therefore make multiple calls to extract more results.

However, when I redo a call, how can I exclude results that I already fetched in a previous call?

One manual way is to add each line in the search, but is there a way to do this programmatically?

Comment: withing your `GSJA` panel, you can define the number of retrieved  results per request AFAIR, and in case if you would like to avoid duplicates, you can append the `urls` to `set`, and if you care about the sort of order, so you can say like `if that is not in data: data.append(that)`

Comment: Can you explain the urls to set? In the http get request?

Comment: well, are you scraping the returned urls from the `API`?

Comment: Yes, but if I redo the query, I want to avoid retrieving the same sites, as the max of results is 10 per request. So I would like to start with result 40 if I have 1 to 30.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I misunderstand the question, but the 'start' parameter is how you paginate through results.  See https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/cse/list

Answer (score 0):

Imagine the following as the returned `output` from the `API`:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<a class="result" href="www.test1.com" </a>
<a class="result" href="www.test1.com" </a>
<a class="result" href="www.test2.com" </a>
<a class="result" href="www.test2.com" </a>
<a class="result" href="www.test3.com" </a>
<a class="result" href="www.test3.com" </a>
"""


soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')


urls = [url.get("href") for url in soup.findAll("a", class_="result")]

print(set(urls))
```

Output:

```
{'www.test3.com', 'www.test2.com', 'www.test1.com'}
```

As you can see `set` is actually remove the duplicates but it doesn't care about the order.

But if you care about the order. so use `list` as the following:

```py
items = []

for item in soup.findAll("a", class_="result"):
    item = item.get("href")
    if item not in items:
        items.append(item)

print(items)
```

Output:

```
['www.test1.com', 'www.test2.com', 'www.test3.com']
```

So you can loop over your `calls` to the `API` and `add` to set or `append` to `list`.